# Google play api references not recognized

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm following https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

And I can't get the project buttonclicker2000 to compile.

See the screenshot below.

[image: Failed imports]

Comment: Be sure that you have installed the Google Repository from the SDK Manager and that you have included the correct package and version in the dependencies of `build.gradle`

Comment: If you are using the exact directory structure of the GitHub project, these settings are in `BasicSamples / libraries / BaseGameUtils / build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the import statements in grey must be added to your project libraries.

At the link you provided, https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples, go into the scripts folder, then into the eclipse_aux folder. Download the .jar file within and save it somewhere you can find.

Now in Android Studio, in the left project tree, right click on "ButtonClicker" > New > Module

Then select the Import .JAR/.AAR Package option.

You can click the "browse" [...] on the far right and locate your jar. 
Sync the project: right click app > Sync app

You should be golden after that. Alt-Shift over RED methods/code relevant to your added library and you should now be able to quick import.

Comment: All this work shouldn't be necessary if the gradle script is set up correctly.

Comment: You're right, wasn't looking at the package details, didn't realize it was Google. For any other "random" libraries out there, this is a pain free way as it will deal with gradle.

Comment: I am indeed golden, aside from "cannot resolve symbol R" which I'm guessing will be fixed as I continue the tutorial.  Thanks!

Comment: On compile and run it should go away. Sometimes its wonky between gradle builds.